# Two separate images to run spark in client-mode using Kubernetes, Python with Apache-Spark 3.2.0?

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I deployed Apache Spark 3.2.0 using this script run from a distribution folder for Python:

`./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r <repo> -t my-tag -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build`

I can create a container under K8s using Spark-Submit just fine.  My goal is to run spark-submit configured for client mode vs. local mode and expect additional containers will be created for the executors.

Does the image I created allow for this, or do I need to create a second image (without the -p option) using the docker-image tool and configure within a different container ?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that only one image is needed if you're running PySpark.  Using Client-mode, the code spawns the executors and workers for you and they run once you create a spark-submit command.  Big improvement from Spark version 2.4!